# Cufflinks for plotly: setting cufflinks config options launches

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to use [`cufflinks`](https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/cufflinks/) locally to generate plotly graphs from a pandas `Dataframe`

However, when I try and configure cufflinks in a python console, it then goes into ipython mode:

```
>>> import cufflinks as cf
>>> cf.set_config_file(offline=True)
In :
```

Subsequently, when I try and generate a plot, nothing appears:

```
In : df.iplot(kind='bar', barmode='stack', filename='cufflinks/test')
In :
```

Can cufflinks be used offline without a plotly account?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the issue is setting the filename argument in the `iplot` call.

`df.iplot(kind='bar', barmode='stack')`

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/santosjorge/5fdbe947496faf7af5e6

**Edit** if it is possible to do this with plotly, you can pass your cufflinks-generated figure to plotly.plot:

```
import cufflinks as cf
import plotly as py
fig = df.iplot(kind='bar', barmode='stack', asFigure=True)
py.offline.plot(fig)
```

Comment: That's the thing - I'm trying to use it in a scipt, i.e. not in ipython, jupyter or anything like that. Do you know if it can be used like that?

Comment: Ah, I don't think plotly currently has support to save generated charts automatically to a local file.

Comment: Plotly definitely has that capability - you can save a file or generate an HTML `div` for embedding in another file - https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/ 

I'm sure cufflinks can work offline too, I just need to figure out how to do it.....

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me (assuming you have a folder name cufflinks):

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly
import cufflinks as cf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, 
plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()


# Offline html saving
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 3), columns=['A','B','C']).cumsum()
fig = df.iplot(asFigure=True)
plotly.offline.plot(fig,filename="cufflinks/example.html")
```

Answer (score 5):

@elsherbini and @Charon: unfortunately I have not enough credentials to comment, so I have to write a new answer.
your code pointed me into the right direction, but with the latest cufflinks version it goes even simpler:

```
import cufflinks as cf
df.iplot(kind='bar', barmode='stack', filename="my_barplot" , asPlot=True)
```

This code will generate a my_barplot.html file and open the plot in the default web browser.
And this code is scriptable.

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from plotly import __version__
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs,plot,iplot    

cf.go_offline()
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,4),columns = 'A B C D'.split())
print("\nHead for df : \n",df.head())

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Category':['A','B','C'],'Values':[32,43,50]})
print("\ndf2 : \n",df2)

df.iplot(asPlot=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

just use this:

```
import cufflinks as cf

cf.set_config_file(offline=True)
```

[image]