# How to view graph created by cufflinks/plotly using spyder IDE

Tags: python, plotly, spyder

I'm running the code below to try and create a simple scatter plot of of the dataframe OAT_df. The code runs fine but nothing appears? How do I find the graph that is produced?  See code below

OAT_df.iplot(kind = 'scatter', filename = 'cufflinks/simple-line')

Comment: Looks like this issue was resolved on a different thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746074/cufflinks-for-plotly-setting-cufflinks-config-options-launches

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cufflinks for plotly: setting cufflinks config options launches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746074/cufflinks-for-plotly-setting-cufflinks-config-options-launches)

Comment: If that command generates a Plotly plot then it can't be displayed in Spyder. The problem is Plotly generates a mix of HTML and Javascript, and that can't be shown in Spyder consoles, sorry.